# Grails: How to make everything I create Upper Case?

Tags: groovy, uppercase, grails, linkfieldvalue

I am currently using CSS to change everything I write to upperCase when I create an entry, but that is not enough. When I save things, the text shown in the text fields is upper case, but the real value that Grails stores stays in lower case.

I am assuming I'd need to change something in the controller or anything.

Maybe transforming the $fieldValue CSS could work??

Any ideas would help!

Thnks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could just write setters for your domain object?

```
class Domain {
 String aField

 void setAField( String s ){
   aField = s?.toUpperCase()
 }
}
```

Comment: @hvgotcodes ;) your way might be quicker if there's thousands of properties tho :) or maybe some sort of httpfilter

Comment: @fgualda87 yeah, this method would require a setter for every uppercase prop

Comment: yeah I only have 3 or 4 so I'll use your way, thanks to both!!

Answer (score 5):

Using annotations is cleanest approach

```
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
class Person {
    @BindingFormat('UPPERCASE')
    String someUpperCaseString

    @BindingFormat('LOWERCASE')
    String someLowerCaseString
}
```

Here is link for it: [Grails doc for data binding](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking how to change values on your domain objects to uppercase. If this is not the case please clarify the question.

You have a bunch of options.  I would recommend

1)  In a service method, before you save, using String.toUpperCase() to modify the appropriate values on the domain object.

or

2)  You can use the underlying Hibernate interceptors by defining a beforeInsert method on your domain object, and doing the toUpperCase there. (see 5.5.1 of the grails documentation)

or

3) You could do this client side.  However, if it is a "business requirement" that the values are stored as upper, then I recommend doing the translation server side.  It is easier to wrap tests around that code....

Comment: Which one is shorter? Size is kind of an issue

Comment: @fgualda87 -- i think tim_yates's solutions is better.  and shorter

Answer (score 1):

You can use Groovy metaprogramming to change the setter for all domain class String-typed properties without actually writing a custom setter for each property.

To do this, add something like the following to the `init` closure of `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
   def init = { servletContext ->

      for (dc in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {        

         dc.class.metaClass.setProperty = { String name, value ->

            def metaProperty = delegate.class.metaClass.getMetaProperty(name)

            if (metaProperty) {

               // change the property value to uppercase if it's a String property
               if (value && metaProperty.type == String) {
                  value = value.toUpperCase()
               }

               metaProperty.setProperty(delegate, value)
            } else {
               throw new MissingPropertyException(name, delegate.class)
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: The parameters inside the for should be change to the name of my domain right?

Comment: no, `dc` is just a local variable and `grailsApplication` is an implicit object that is available in `Bootstrap.groovy`, GSPs, and probably some other places too. I think it's an instance of http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.5/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html